# Removing lots of fields from an object's layout

Tags: page-layout

I need to work on a SF layout that is currently a total mess, a lot of custom fields, some even repeated and a generally horrible/confusing layout.

I'm going over how to streamline this drastically, removing lots of the fields.

I just want to check if when approaching such a task there is an optimal way to handle the fields that are removed in terms of future access.  Naturally if I just alter the layout the old data isn't removed but in terms of accessing that old data in those now redundant fields, anyone have any tips?

Comment: Use field trip app to analyse field usage

Comment: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HSXEEA4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get to the data through the UI, I would suggest a second page layout that is assigned to the system admin...perhaps sticking the fields on a single section.

If it is just a matter of getting to the data at all, you can use Data Loader, or one of the many data management tools to work with the data.

Eventually you might look at removing the fields entirely, as the extra fields can make writing reports more confusing. But any such changes should first be undertaken in a Sandbox, tested, and then finally moved into production.